# Hibernate throws could not resolve property when i do the following operation

Tags: java, hibernate

```
public class UserRole implements java.io.Serializable {
    /** */
    private long id;

    /** */
    private UserAcegi userAcegi;
    /**
     * 
     */
    public UserRole() {
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param idVar -
     */
    public UserRole(final int idVar) {
        this.id = idVar;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param idVar -
     * @param roleVar -
     * @param userAcegiVar -
     */
    public UserRole(final int idVar, final UserAcegi userAcegiVar) {
        this.id = idVar;

        this.userAcegi = userAcegiVar;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @return long
     */
    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param idVar -
     */
    public void setId(final long idVar) {
        this.id = idVar;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return UserAcegi
     */
    public UserAcegi getuserAcegi() {
        return this.userAcegi;
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param userAcegiVar -
     */
    public void setuserAcegi(final UserAcegi userAcegiVar) {
        this.userAcegi = userAcegiVar;
    }

}
```

---

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="UserRole" table="userrole" >
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="userAcegi" class="UserAcegi" fetch="select">
            <column name="userid" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

===========================================

```
Criteria criteria = ThreadSessionManager.getCurrentThreadSession().currentAccegiSession().createCriteria(UserRole.class);

  criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userAccegi.id", "7300765"));

  final List objList = criteria.list();
  return objList;
```

Comment: Typo? In some places you say `accegi`, in others `acegi`

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace.. and moreover.. also add the xml for `UserAcegi`, as you ae trying to fetch on the basis of `userAccegi.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your this line **criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userAccegi.id", "7300765"));**
as **criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("userAccegi.userid", "7300765"));**

hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to reference the id property of the userAcegi property, then you will likely need to alias the userAcegi property.  It would look something like the following:

```
Criteria criteria = ThreadSessionManager.getCurrentThreadSession().currentAccegiSession().createCriteria(UserRole.class);

criteria.createAlias("userAcegi", "ua", Criteria.INNER_JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ua.id", "7300765"));
```

Hope this helps!